# Workflow for making stroke animations for any script out of existing fonts?

Tags: fonts, animation

I am looking to make [this Hanzi stroke animator](https://hanziwriter.org/demo.html), which has JSON data such as [this](https://github.com/chanind/hanzi-writer-data/blob/master/data/%E3%A5%AF.json), work for any language (as of now, Tibetan, Devanagari, and Tamil). Basically I want to show an animation of how to draw the character.

[image]

What is the recommended workflow for doing this for a given script?

1. Find a font you would like represented in the animation.
2. Learn the stroke pattern for each glyph from some website.
3. Edit each font glyph to have strokes be separated somehow?
4. Export each glyph as SVG?
5. Take SVG paths and convert to JSON, and then plug into the Hanzi animator. (I can probably do this, but probably not the other steps as I don't know much about fonts as a software engineer).

Is this a good workflow? Any edge cases I need to be aware of? Tangent question, how hard would it be for a font designer to make it so each glyph was divided into the proper strokes, assuming they aren't super familiar with each script (Devanagari, Tibetan, etc.)? Is that a hard process, or easy?

Comment: Your approach sounds on point to me. There could possibly be a tool out there to do this already (at least for a specific font)?

Comment: Number 3 is most of the work. Allmost to the point where it would make sense to do the font yourself.